# chrome extension script is loading twice even more on some pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

this is my background.js file

```
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,info, tab) {
    var sites =new Array('site2','site1');
    var url=tab.url;
    var siteFlag=0;
    for(var i in sites) {
       var regexp = new RegExp('.*' + sites[i] + '.*','i');
       if (regexp.test(url)) {siteFlag=1;}
    };
    if(siteFlag==1){
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file:"contentscript.js"});
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file:"jquery.js"});
      chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabId,{file:"box.css"});
    }
 });
```

In the contentscript.js I simply run a popup box.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function popup() {...}
    if (window.addEventListener)
    {
        window.addEventListener('load', popup(), false); 
    } 
    else if (window.attachEvent)
    {
        window.attachEvent('onload', popup());
    }
});
```

There are some pages that there are one popup-box and there are pages that two or even more

what is the problem?

=============EDIT==================

those pages contain Iframes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension - Content Script being injected multiple times per single page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829895/chrome-extension-content-script-being-injected-multiple-times-per-single-page)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` is fired when tab status changes, this has nothing to do with iframes. Your script is injected multiple times to the same frame because you inject it for each status change, and you want to inject it only when status changes to "complete". Modify your code by adding `if (changeInfo.status == "complete") {`:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,info, tab) {
   if (info.status == "complete") {
      /* checking & injecting stuff */
   }
});
```

Comment: Woooaaahh. I've been using if(tabs['status'] != 'complete'){return;} and this caused my script to run multiple times every update. Switching to using changeInfo.status completely stopped this! 48 hours of my life gone!!

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure why the content scripts load twice. But I had this problem too. I added the following to the "content_scripts" element in manifest.json and it worked just fine.

```
"content_scripts" : [
    {
        "all_frames" : false,
        "run_at" : "document_end",
    }
]
```

**So finally, manifest.json:**

```
{
    "name": "ABC",
    "version": "0.0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "key": "longkeyhere",
    "description": "Description",
    "minimum_chrome_version": "29",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "jquery.js",
            "jquery.min.js",
        ]
    },
    "content_scripts" : [
        {
            "all_frames" : false,
            "run_at" : "document_end",
            "matches" : [ "http://*/*" ],
            "js" : [
                "jquery.js",
                "jquery.min.js",
            ]
        }
    ],
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "contextMenus",
        "tabs",
        "identity",
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

Comment: yes,   `"all_frames" : false, ` helped for youtube.com but it was always working fine ok with `true` value for all years <= 2022 but then a new Chrome updates broke something

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is caused by pages using frames. The script gets loaded for each frame. You might be able to detect in which frame you are loaded, or whether one frame already has your script if you absolutely want to execute your script only once.

Comment: If anchor div for js content is being created check like so would work:  --->

export const createDomAnchor = (anchorId: string) => {
 if (!document.getElementById(anchorId)) {
  const anchor = document.createElement('div');
  anchor.id = anchorId;
  document.body.insertBefore(anchor, document.body.childNodes[0]);
 }
};

Answer (score 1):

You can control your content script execution using manifest file of your extension:
You can prevent your content script from loading into iframes or a specific set of urls.
Here is an sample manifest section:

```
"all_frames": true,
 "js": [ "ContentOnDocStart.js" ],
 "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
 "exclude_matches": [ ],
 "run_at": "document_start"
```

Comment: yes,   `"all_frames" : false, ` helped for youtube.com but it was always working fine ok with `true` value for all years <= 2022 but then a new Chrome updates broke something