# Prevent content script from loading multiple times due to page iframes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My extension's `contentscript` is loading multiple times in a page containing multiple iframes. Is there a way to prevent this?

I've tried doing the suggestion of this related post: [chrome extension script is loading twice even more on some pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148677/chrome-extension-script-is-loading-twice-even-more-on-some-pages) but it still loads multiple times.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tab.status === 'complete' && changeInfo.status === "complete") {
        chrome.browserAction.getBadgeText({}, function(result) {
            if (result === "ON") {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "js/contentscript.js", allFrames: true, runAt: "document_idle" }, result => {
                        // Ignores the permission issue when trying to inject the
                        // content script to local file of chrome extension.
                        const lastErr = chrome.runtime.lastError;
                        if (lastErr) return;
                    });
                }, 100);
            }
        });
    } else {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: "(c = document.querySelectorAll('#button')) ? c.forEach(panel => { panel.parentNode.removeChild(panel); }) : null;" },
            result => {
                // Ignores the permission issue when trying to inject the
                // content script to local file of chrome extension.
                const lastErr = chrome.runtime.lastError;
                if (lastErr) return;
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: You're specifying `allFrames:true` so each frame gets an instance of the content script - this is how content scripts work.

Comment: I've also tried changing that, but the issue still persists

Comment: You need to reload your extension when you edit the background script. Anyway, without seeing the extension I have to guess. Maybe you declare content_scripts in manifest.json which is not needed with executeScript.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Delete that, it's false by default